# When is ignorance of the law an excuse?

Tags: halacha, beit-din-court, capital-punishment

In capital cases (say, murder or adultery), ignorance of the law is a valid
defense. A Jewish court requires two witnesses to give evidence that the
defendant was taught ahead of time that his action carries the death
penalty. Without that warning, he cannot be convicted.

Are there any other cases in which ignorance of the law is a valid excuse?  Sources?

Comment: What do you mean by "valid defense"?

Comment: The beis din cannot impose any punishment for violating any halakha unless the person was verbally warned immediately before the violation that the thing he was about to do is forbidden and the punishment is XYZ and the person acknowledges the warning and does it anyway.

Comment: source please...

Comment: A murderer who wasn't warned is still executed via indirect means.  See, e.g., Maimonides Laws of Murder 4:8: הַהוֹרֵג נְפָשׁוֹת וְלֹא הָיוּ עֵדִים רוֹאִין אוֹתוֹ כְּאַחַת אֶלָּא רָאָהוּ הָאֶחָד אַחַר הָאֶחָד אוֹ שֶׁהָרַג בִּפְנֵי שְׁנֵי עֵדִים בְּלֹא הַתְרָאָה אוֹ שֶׁהֻכְחֲשׁוּ הָעֵדִים בִּבְדִיקוֹת וְלֹא הֻכְחֲשׁוּ בַּחֲקִירוֹת. כָּל אֵלּוּ הָרַצְחָנִים כּוֹנְסִין אוֹתָן לְכִפָּה וּמַאֲכִילִין אוֹתָן לֶחֶם צַר וּמַיִם לַחַץ עַד שֶׁיָּצֵרוּ מֵעֵיהֶן וְאַחַר כָּךְ מַאֲכִילִין אוֹתָן שְׂעוֹרִים עַד שֶׁתִּבָּקַע כְּרֵסָם מִכֹּבֶד הַחלִי:

Comment: @Loewian -- What is the Rambam's source for "Rambam, Laws of Murder 4;8: Someone who commits murder without two eyewitnesses who can testify together, or committed the murder in front of two witnesses but without formal warning, or that the witnesses contradicted each other in ancillary parts of their testimony, all such murderers are incarcerated in a kippah [a small enclosure, with little room to move around], and they feed him low rations of bread and water, until their intestines are in pain, and then they feed them barley until their stomach explodes from the weight of the illness."   ?

Comment: Mishna Sanhedrin 81b

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Murderer_and_the_Preservation_of_Life.4.8?lang=bi&with=Sanhedrin&lang2=en

Comment: There is also the final option of referring the individual to the King who can, for example, send the person on an extremely dangerous mission.

Comment: What's there to downvote in a straightforward question on Jewish law?  Silly games...

Comment: There are dinim of hatraa, indeed following rabbi yose a talmid chacham doesn't need hatraa because he has the knowledge of halacha. But I think that this is not the halacha. So, your example is not a proof that lack of knowledge is the excuse.

Comment: An interesting question, +1, I don't understand downvotes. What you ask is that in some cases the Gemmorah makes a difference in the need for warning between a layman and a scholar, and suggests that in some cases we don't need a warning for scholars, implying they are aware of what they do. In all other cases not the warning, but **the defendant's reply is what incriminates him** - once he says explicitly that he's aware of the crime AND the expected punishment.

Answer (score 3):

Anytime someone does something due to lack of knowledge that it is forbidden he is a  Shoggeg. That is not a defense but it makes his action less severe.

The lack of warning by capital crimes is not a defense either. Receiving a warning first is a prerequisite to receiving the death penalty. But the lack of one is not a defense in the sense of being exonerated.

Comment: Can you provide a source?